# disable CPPickerView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uipickerview

I'm making an iPhone/iPad app where I have PickerView. For PickerView, I am using [`CPPickerView`](https://github.com/cbpowell/CPPickerView).

I'm trying to disable this pickerview and to do that, I wrote this code:

```
[realEstatePV setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

However, above is not working. I can still move the CPPickerView.

Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. So i updated the `CPPickerView`, and its very easy.

Open `CPPickerView.h` and add a method declaration

```
- (void)enabled:(BOOL)val;
```

Now open `CPPickerView.m`and add implementation method.

```
-(void)enabled:(BOOL)val {
    self.contentView.scrollEnabled = val;
}
```

Its done......

Now You can disable CPPickerView like this.

```
[realEstatePV enabled:NO];
```

To enable again use

```
[realEstatePV enabled:YES];
```

Hope this helps.